# What is the difference from overwriting a nonvirtual function and a virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

In C++: What is the difference from overwriting a nonvirtual function and overwriting a virtual one?

Comment: Overwriting means nothing. Do you want to ask about member function hiding, overriding or overloading? Search for each here if you want to clarify your question.

Comment: In case no one mentions it: please consult [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and buy yourself a good book on C++.

Answer (score 8):

With `virtual`:

```
class Base {
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "Foo in Base" << std::endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "Foo in Derived" << std::endl;}
};

// in main()
Derived* d = new Derived();
d->Foo(); // prints "Foo in Derived"

Base* b = new Derived();
b->Foo(); // prints "Foo in Derived"
```

and without (same code, but leave out the `virtual`):

```
// in main() 
Derived* d = new Derived();
d->Foo(); // prints "Foo in Derived"

Base* b = new Derived();
b->Foo(); // prints "Foo in Base"
```

so the difference is that without `virtual`, there is no true runtime polymorphism: which function is called is decided by the compiler depending on the current type of the pointer/reference through which it is called.

With `virtual`, the objects maintains a list of virtual functions (`vtable`) in which it looks up the actual address of the function to call - at runtime, every time you call a virtual member of it. In this sample, the entry for `Foo` is implicitly modified by the `Derived` constructor to point to the overridden function so it doesn't matter that `Foo` is called through an `Base`-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting a virtual function will ensure that the type of the object is assessed at runtime and the appropriate method is called.

Example:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
   void PrintType(); // Prints "Vehicle"
};

class Car: public Vehicle
{
 // overwrite PrintType to print "Car"
};


// In main
void main()
{
Vehicle *s = new Car();
s->PrintType();  // Prints "Vehicle"

// If PrintType was virtual then the type of s will be evaluated at runtime and the inherited function will be called printing "Car"
}
```